# Redis with java

Tags: java, redis

```
public void verProduto(){
    //System.out.println("Digite o codigo do produto : - ");
    //produt.setCodigo(scan.nextInt());

    List<String> list =  (List<String>) jeproduto.keys("*"); 

for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) { 
    System.out.println("List of stored keys:: "+list.get(i)); 
}  
}
```

This code returns error:

> java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.List

Could someone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) and that the `jeproduto` object is a `Jedis` instance, per the [javadocs](http://static.javadoc.io/redis.clients/jedis/2.9.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#keys-java.lang.String-), the `keys` method returns the type `Set<String>`

You have two options:

Change your collection type to a Set instead of a List:

```
Set<String> keySet = jeproduto.keys("*");
for (String key : keySet) {
    System.out.println("List of stored keys: " + key); 
}
```

**Or**

If you truly need a List, do what CannedMoose mentioned and take advantage of the ArrayList constructor that allows you to pass another collection.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(jeproduto.keys("*"));
```

Comment: Does anybody care to explain the downvote on this valid, accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

You havent given a lot of detail but you can try:

```
List<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>(jeproduto.keys("*"));
```

Comment: They are different types, so it is basically a problem of assigning different types. It seems `jeproduto` is an implementation of `Map`, `Set` or the like. At least `keys()` seems to return a `Set`. A `List` is a different interface with a different set of methods. `ArrayList` implements the `List` interface (so you can assign it a `List`) and supplies a constructor that accepts a `Collection`. And a `Set` implements the `Collection` interface.

Answer (score -1):

```
Since your code is not fully completed.

My Assumption is
   jeproduto = new HashSet<String>


then

List<String> list =  (List<String>) jeproduto.keys("*"); line should be
// Creating a List of HashSet elements
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(hset);


 if you want to convert Hashset to List, please find the sample code below.

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Create a HashSet
      HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<String>();

      //add elements to HashSet
      hset.add("A");
      hset.add("B");
      hset.add("C");
      hset.add("D");
      hset.add("E");

      // Displaying HashSet elements
      System.out.println("HashSet contains: "+ hset);

      // Creating a List of HashSet elements
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(hset);

      // Displaying ArrayList elements
      System.out.println("ArrayList contains: "+ list);
  }
```

Comment: There is no such method "keys" on the Java object HashSet

Comment: Yes, i am agree, I said List<String> list =  (List<String>) jeproduto.keys("*"); line should be
// Creating a List of HashSet elements
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(hset);

Comment: please see the comments carefully. I didn't mention that keys are present in HashSet, i said line should be changed to as per my comments.

Comment: But OP asked specifically about `jeproduto.keys("*")`, so this answer is worthless to them.

Comment: They want to convert the jeproducto.keys("*) to List, so above code will be useful List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(jeproduto.keys("*")); will work out